# Nothing happens when I delete textures in android opengl

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to delete all the textures in my scene while it is rendering to test if they actually delete. Nothing happens. The screen just keeps rendering the textures that were supposed to have been deleted.

```
public static void deleteAllTextures() {
    int[] deltextures = new int[1];
    for (String keys : textures.keySet()) {
        deltextures[0] = textures.get(keys).getGlLocation();
        deleteTexture(deltextures);
    }

    GLES20.glFlush();
    //textures.clear(); commented out so I can see if opengl deletes textures.
}

private static void deleteTexture(int texture[]){
        GLES20.glDeleteTextures(1, texture, 0);
    }
```

Comment: Are you deleting the textures after you've already issued the rendering commands that use them?  Or are you using the textures after the deletion?

Comment: I'm still rendering after they are deleted and they still render.

Comment: So the GLES implementation is still accepting the texture IDs as valid, even after the glDeleteTextures() call has returned?  Which device is this on?

Comment: Are the textures referenced somewhere else, e.g. used as an FBO attachment? Or are you using multiple contexts?